# Dynamic Mongoose Find using AND style query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a situation where the user may enter multiple constraints to return back results on.  I am trying to perform a "find" in mongoose that I can perform multiple "and"s on. I thought the first block below would return back my results but rather it returns back all results currently in my db. My end goal I was trying to achieve is from the two hex value entries of both "5B6D8B" AND "BA4D2A" provide me the path only if the perc >= 5.  If I just pass "{hex: "5B6D8B", 'img.perc': {$gte: 5} }" to find it pulls back a single result which is correct.

```
clrModel.find([{hex: "5B6D8B", 'img.perc': {$gte: 5} },
{hex: "BA4D2A", 'img.perc': {$gte: 5} }] ,'img.path', function(error,data){});
```

The second part to this is I would like to, if possible, build the value passed to "find" dynamically. It seems that I can't pass it as a string as it doesn't work.  Any ideas on how I can achieve this?  The below block is what I was trying to do but it doesnt work. Unsure if it will help in better understanding what I was attempting to do. "finalFind" that is shown below is the result I would pass as the first param to the find query.  Thanks in advance!

```
var hex, perc, finalFind = '{';
for(var i = 0; i < numIndicies; i++){
    finalFind += '{hex:"' + hexArr[i] + '", {perc: {$gte:' + percArr[i] + '}}}';
    //Handle our end character
    if(i !== numIndicies-1)
        finalFind += ',';
    else
        finalFind += '}';
}
```

------- Edit Below Showing Document Example --------

The below item is representative of a document entry

```
{
    "__v": 0,
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "51c1ac95f502f20969000022"
    },
    "hex": "BA4D2A",
    "img": [
        {
            "path": "http://example.com/image1.jpg",
            "perc": 10,
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "51c1ac95f502f20969000023"
            }
        },
        {
            "path": "http://example.com/image2.jpg",
            "perc": 20,
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "51c1ac95f502f20969000034"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can't have an AND with 2 values for the same property (hex) as that's not possible, so I assume you want both an AND clause and an OR clause like below. AND is the default for your conditions object, so you just need to `$or` your hex values.

```
clrModel.find({
  'img.perc': {$gte: 5},
  $or: [
    {hex: "5B6D8B"},
    {hex: "BA4D2A"}
  ]
}, 'img.path', function(error,data) {....
```

Another variant that should return the same results:

```
clrModel.find({
  'img.perc': {$gte: 5},
  hex: {$in: ["5B6D8B", "BA4D2A"]}
}, 'img.path', function(error,data) {....
```

Comment: Thanks Peter!  That was stupid on my part.  I was thinking that if I used or it would only return one or the other, rather I should have been thinkin of it from a query standpoint. As you probably already know, this worked awesome!  Any ideas on how I might be able to convert something like "["5B6D8B", "BA4D2A"]" into an object that I can pass to the hex entry hex: {$in: ["5B6D8B", "BA4D2A"]} ?  When I use JSON.parse it gives me an error stating there is an extra character ','. I am going to set this as resolved, as my main issue was solved.  Thanks again!

Comment: My guess is you are building a string array of hex values in a loop and your code puts an extra comma at the end. However, I think you are unnecessarily going from an array of strings to a JSON string back to an array of strings. Just use `hex: {$in: hexArr}` directly.

Comment: Last question, I promise :) My documents in the db looks like the entry in my edit above. If I wanted to pull back the documents matching my hex where the subdocument img.perc value was greater than 5 for example, can I perform a nested query in the line below? Each of the documents contains a different hex value. So in the array passed I would want to only select it if the percentage matched as well.
    hex: {$in: ["5B6D8B", "BA4D2A"]}

Comment: Please just submit a separate question. Extended comment threads are discouraged.